# PHP MySQL OpenSSL Warning

Tags: php, mysql, openssl

I am running PHP 7.2.9 on localhost (Windows) with MySQL.  Whenever I try and connect to my local MySQL, I get the following warning:

**"PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): PHP was built without OpenSSL extension, can't send password encrypted in [path]"**

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    include("db_conn.php");
    $conn = mysqli_connect($endpoint, $username, $password, $database);
    if($conn) {
        echo('hello world');
    }
?>
```

[I verified that the OpenSSL extension is loading via PHP -m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iclLf.png)

What am I missing?  I'm sure it's a bonehead mistake.

Comment: When you get that notice are you running the script through command line as well?

Comment: No, it's coming up in my browser window.

Comment: The CLI is sometimes different than the server softwares version. Run `phpinfo()` from your browser.

Comment: sometimes there are 2 `ini` files one for CLI one for Apache typically `php-cli.ini` and `php.ini`.  So even if it's enabled on the command line that doesn't mean it's loaded from apache or the http side of things..

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong password for the service account - for some reason its throwing the OpenSSL warning but once I fixed the password the script connects to the database and page renders like it should.

Told you all it was a bonehead mistake ....